# What's the equivalent of hoistEither in scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers

What's the equivalent of `hoistEither :: Monad m => Either e a -> EitherT e m a`?

I have an `\/[E, A]` and I'd like to get a `EitherT[M[_],E,A]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EitherT#fromDisjunction`.

- https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.2.0/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/EitherT.scala#L212-L217
- https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.2.0/tests/src/test/scala/scalaz/EitherTTest.scala#L44